# Is it possible to have an avatar coupled to my Stack Exchange OpenID?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-openid

I commented on a Blogger post using my Stack Exchange OpenID. Next to my name, a small OpenID icon is displayed.

Is it possible to have my network profile avatar coupled to my SE OpenID? I'm not entirely sure if OpenID itself supports avatars.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's not possible, but asking SE to expose the avatar (same as shown in the network profile) would make a fine feature request IMO.